# Why is reputation change on the activity page shown twice?

Tags: support, reputation, design, profile-page

After [the recent profile page changes](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-ones-big/), the activity tab now contains information about *how much reputation we gained since the last visit to reputation tab* twice:

1. Near entire reputation

   [image]
2. and near the link to the *reputation tab*,

   [image]

From what I know both these values can be visible only in one place - at the *activity tab* (unless I missed something), so what is the point to show it there twice?
Is there a possible difference between these values which I am not aware of?

For now only difference I found is lack of number formatting in blue area `1.8k` vs `1755`.

[image]

Comment: I started to post the same question yesterday.  They are only 398px apart on my screen.  I'd like to see the top one be something like rep today rather than repeating the same value in a  different color,

Comment: I would guess it is a holdover from the old profile page that was not updated when they switched to the new profile pages.

Comment: @JoeW That would make sense, but I asked this question to avoid guessing :). Maybe there is something like problem with blue area on mobile version on some devices... (just another guess).